# AS3/Flex blendMode performance issues on mobile devices

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile

I am using a custom item renderer with an image and a line of text. I have the image set to blendMode="luminosity" and when you run it on the desktop air to debug and test it it appears to run perfectly fine without any lag. However if you test it on a mobile device it causes the list to lag a ridiculous amount to the point where it is unusable. If I do this on just one item of the list it will cause the lag to appear. It gets worse the more images there are that use it but even with just one it is clearly evident and practically unusable.

Does anyone know if there is a way to improve the performance of this or is there no work around?

Thanks

Comment: Adobe made special item renderers for mobile apps, to make them more lightweight and hence usable on mobile devices. My gut feeling here is if performance is that bad, you should not try to use blend mode and should stick w/the mobile based renderer classes: `LabelItemRenderer` and `IconItemRenderer`. If your current renderer doesn't extend these classes, that might be a good place to start (while keeping blend mode): `IconItemRender` does some optimization for/images (but nothing related to blend mode).

Comment: Are you testing using "Debug as mobile application"?  If so, do you see the same problem using both "standard" and "fast" packaging options in your Debug Configuration?